# Desmos and mathematica outputting different graphs for the same equation

Tags: plotting

I am new to wolfram mathematica and I am trying to plot multiple functions, however when comparing to the functions on desmos, I get different results, even when copying and pasting the function from mathematica straight into desmos.

One of the equations is:

[image]

I write this into mathematica as:

```
f1[x_] := (0.89 (x - 0.1) (x - 0.2) (x - 0.5) (x - 0.4)/0.004) + (0.815 (x) (x - 0.2) (x - 0.5) (x - 0.4)/-0.0012) + (0.7125 (x) (x - 0.1) (x - 0.5) (x - 0.4)/0.0012) + (0.54 (x) (x - 0.1) (x - 0.2) (x - 0.4)/0.006) + (0.573 (x) (x - 0.1) (x - 0.2) (x - 0.5)/-0.0024) 

Plot[f1[x],{x,0,3}]
```

and it ends up looking like:

[image]

while on desmos it looks like:

[image]

However, If i paste f1[x] directly into the plot function though (see below), I get the correct graph for some reason. Can someone explain what im doing wrong please even if its just a small mistake:

```
Plot[(0.89 (x - 0.1) (x - 0.2) (x - 0.5) (x - 0.4)/0.004) + (0.815 (x) (x - 0.2) (x - 0.5) (x - 0.4)/-0.0012) + (0.7125 (x) (x - 0.1) (x - 0.5) (x - 0.4)/0.0012) + (0.54 (x) (x - 0.1) (x - 0.2) (x - 0.4)/0.006) + (0.573 (x) (x - 0.1) (x - 0.2) (x - 0.5)/-0.0024) ,{x,0,3}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I get the [same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beM6W.png) in both cases. Try clearing your symbols with ``Clear["Global`*"]`` or restarting the kernel with ``Quit[]``. Furthermore, you can modify the aspect ratio with ``Plot[..., AspectRatio->Automatic]`` or fiddle around with ``PlotRange`` to get a more similar plot.

Comment: Ah, you answered it while I was still typing my own! :P

Comment: I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoF4O.png) on v12.2.0 (Win7-x64).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, welcome to mathematica!

### Now let's break down your question:

**I believe that Desmos and mathematica show the same thing**, it is just that desmos is perhaps playing a bit more with the aspect ratio of the plot as well as the plot range.

For example, in your case, I just had to change the settings for the Plot and I can recover the figure that you have in Desmos:

```
f1[x_] := (0.89 (x - 0.1) (x - 0.2) (x - 0.5) (x - 0.4)/
     0.004) + (0.815 (x) (x - 0.2) (x - 
      0.5) (x - 0.4)/-0.0012) + (0.7125 (x) (x - 0.1) (x - 
      0.5) (x - 0.4)/
     0.0012) + (0.54 (x) (x - 0.1) (x - 0.2) (x - 0.4)/
     0.006) + (0.573 (x) (x - 0.1) (x - 0.2) (x - 0.5)/-0.0024)
Plot[f1[x], {x, -0.5, 1}, PlotRange -> {-0.5, 1.5}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1.5]
```

[image]

---

### A minor comment

What is intriguing to me is the first plot that you showed in your post.
Is it possible that you had defined `f1` again which then overruled your first definition?

You can check this by restarting mathematica from scratch, open a brand new notebook, and then copy paste exactly what you have written in this post.

Let us know!

A.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I think I had an organisation error in my document or something like this. I deleted everything and restarted and it was fine.

Comment: You're most welcome. But again, if you can get your hands on the desktop version of mathematica it is what I would recommend you use. best of luck.